# Closed form of a series with multiplication of odd number

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am wondering what is the closed form of the following series:

$$1 + (-2x)+\frac{(-2x)^2}{1*3}+\frac{(-2x)^3}{1*3*5}+....$$

Actually this is the attempt from the series:

$$1-2x+\frac{4x^2}{3}-\frac{8x^3}{15}+...$$

Cheers

Comment: Where does this series come from? What are your attempts?

Comment: This is the attempt I got from $1-2x+\frac{4x^2}{3}-\frac{8x^3}{15}+...$ :)

Comment: The denominator can be written using the double factorial notation n!!, Which means to skip every other number, in other words for odd numbers only you can use (2n+1)!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2x)^n}{(2n-1)!!}=1-\sqrt{\pi x }\, e^{-x} \, \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$ where appears [the imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html).

It can also write $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2x)^n}{(2n-1)!!}=1-2 \sqrt{x}\,F\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$ where appears [the Dawson integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html) .